# Why does it make a difference how I launch an Excel VBA application on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, office-365

I have Office 365 on a PC running Windows 11 and on a Mac Mini running Sonoma. Both Office versions are up-to-date. I develop an Excel VBA application on Widows. After testing thoroughly, I copy the .xlsm file via OneDrive over to Mac for testing there. I have been doing this for several years with the same application, and have gone through many rounds of testing on both Windows and Mac. But something seems to have changed recently.

Today, I ran the application on Mac in the usual way by double clicking the .xlsm file that I just brought over from the PC. The application halted with an Overflow error. In the Debugger, this assignment statement was flagged:

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 77
```

This obviously should not overflow. I was able to execute the line without raising an error by single stepping in the debugger. But when I let the program continue to run, it halted with an overflow at some other trivial assignment. Same story: single stepping in the debugger does not raise the error.

I decided to try launching Excel in a different way. In Finder, I went to Applications, and double clicked Excel.app. In the Open window, I chose my .xlsm file. Now the application ran faultlessly. To make sure it wasn't a fluke, I ran the test several times this way and it worked every time.

My question is this: On a Mac, what's the difference between (1) double-clicking an .xlsm file and (2) running Excel.app and then selecting the .xlsm file in the Open window?

```
john@Johns-Mac-mini ~ % ls -dleO@ /Users/john/Desktop/BTNS\ System\ Testing\ -\ Mac/March\ 2\,\ 2024/Process\ Profiler-129.xlsm
-rw-rw----@ 1 john  staff  - 308577 Mar  2 15:47 /Users/john/Desktop/BTNS System Testing - Mac/March 2, 2024/Process Profiler-129.xlsm
    com.apple.FinderInfo        32 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS       16 
    com.apple.macl      72 
    com.apple.quarantine        30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For various reasons, macOS sets a quarantine attribute for files loaded via the Internet. This prevents such files from being executed directly.

To fix

- open Terminal
- type `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine` followed by a space
- drag&drop the file in question into the Terminal window
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: The xattr command removes the quarantined attributes, but when I run the application, the quarantined attributes are restored, and I get the same odd runtime behavior (sporadic overflow errors, etc.). I should mention that this time, I passed the files from Windows to Mac in a zip file, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @jisner this looks as if OneDrive adds the attribute again. Two things to try: A) right-Click the file and select Open. B) move the file away from OneDrive, remove the attribute and try again.

Comment: I moved the file from Windows to Mac on a USB stick. On Mac, there were no quarantine attributes. As an experiment, I opened the application with macros disabled, then immediately saved. After saving, the quarantine attributes had been added.  So Mac is adding them. I'm not sure if the quarantined attributes are actually hurting me. I have gotten through an entire system test with no ill effects.

Comment: If I move the file through OneDrive, the file arrives without the quarantined attributes.  But opening and closing the file adds the quarantined attributes. I never open the files in OneDrive. I always move them outside.

Comment: https://book.hacktricks.xyz/macos-hardening/macos-security-and-privilege-escalation/macos-security-protections/macos-sandbox

The above article explains why Mac adds the quarantine attributes when I open and run a VBA application, and restores them even after I remove them with xattr. 

"Everything created/modified by a Sandboxed application will get the quarantine attribute. This will prevent a sandbox space by triggering Gatekeeper if the sandbox app tries to execute something with open."